# Can this layout be accomplished in BS4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I have a website that uses BS4.  There is one content block that I would like to change so that the content is stacked (Title then Image then Content) while on a mobile device and that switches to having the image on the left with the title and copy on the right.

```css
@media screen and (min-width:992px) {
    .float-md-right {
        float: right;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center float-md-right">
          <h1>Title</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
          <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/400/any" style="margin:10px">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 float-md-right">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eget vulputate sem, in semper arcu. Aenean eget leo eu libero condimentum bibendum. Pellentesque quam nulla, scelerisque ut pretium eget, ultricies non nisl. Fusce quis justo ullamcorper, aliquam
            urna consequat, porta justo. Pellentesque a suscipit purus. Ut ullamcorper efficitur diam, eu rutrum lorem facilisis in. Phasellus tincidunt nec elit non dapibus. Cras non vulputate neque. Maecenas nec lobortis urna, id rhoncus sem. Mauris
            facilisis, ante at ornare faucibus, mi lorem congue ligula, non interdum neque risus ac quam. Pellentesque porta tincidunt tortor ac euismod. Sed maximus felis fermentum tincidunt dapibus. Morbi pretium porta augue, id varius tellus sodales
            eu.
          </p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[See above on Codepen](https://codepen.io/swansondesigns/full/LrpWMQ/)

(I can't seem to get the CSS to work in this.  It works on Codepen.)

At the moment, I can only seem to get this to work using BS3, with one element borrowed from BS4 ([responsive floats](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/#responsive)) added to the CSS manually.

So, I have two questions:

1. Is there an easier way to do this with BS3 that I'm missing?
2. Is this possible *at all* in BS4?

Comment: here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MXaLvm  looks like a fast solution

Comment: one more way: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WyQPXx . That's all uses BS3

Comment: Hi Banzay - Thanks for your replies.  But the layout I'm trying to accomplish puts the title above the content in the desktop view.  These have the title above the image.  The tricky part here is getting the image to be between the title and content on mobile, but in its own column on desktop.  Does that make sense?